# Renaming WebSphere after disk cloning

Tags: migration, disk-cloning, websphere

I know it is not the correct ways, but since keeping other installed stuffs is needed.
Does anyone have the steps of renaming a WebSphere Server after cloning at disk level ?

Any help are welcome.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681177/165358) help?

Comment: That is for a normal renaming inside the system, those are labels only. for which you can do at the web administration console already, only tidous works. But my situation is that the renaming occur at host level, the AIX hostID and /etc/hostname are changed. Thus the administrative console will point to the original server if started carelessly. In additional, The WebSphere Server have it's Deployment Manager and also IHS isntalled together.

Comment: actually IBM did have this [document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007419&aid=1), but this only handle around 70% of my problems only, I still cannot get the thing running smooth.

Comment: These might also be useful: [one](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4175.pdf) and [two](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0705_willenborg/0705_willenborg.html).

Comment: The first one is irrelevant, but the 2nd one is exactly what i am looking for, but the funny thing is, there isn't a ConfigWAS.sh at the beginning, and it seems that it is not likely there is an "Export" button. I guess that what some consultant told me is executing the 2nd method. now i have to figure out how i can build that ConfigWAS.sh, it was a 400 page word doc.....

Comment: Search out anything that is named ConfigWAS, since I have also seen mentioned ConfigWAS.pl, as in [this doc](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0708_he/0708_he.html).

Comment: @harrymc, that configWAS is like a house painting, which varies depends on the systems. they will not be the same. Right now i am an engineer which a house owner want me to duplicate his beloved house to next states, for which now i have totally no idea what paint or the layout of his existing one. Hopefully there would be a scanner which can comes up with the receipts.

Comment: I'm not very good on scanners. Sorry, but I have reached my limits on this subject.

Comment: Cross-posting [to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131784/renaming-websphere-after-disk-cloning) [different](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73179/renaming-websphere-after-disk-cloning) [sites](http://serverfault.com/questions/501337/renaming-websphere-after-disk-cloning) is considered abusive behavior. Please stop doing that.

Comment: I have added as an answer the reference you preferred, just so that there will be some answer to this post. If you have resolved your problem with ConfigWAS, please feel free to modify my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article contains the procedure to use :
[Using virtual image templates to deploy WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0705_willenborg/0705_willenborg.html).

However, the poster had some practical problems when applying the article to his case.
In particular, the part about using ConfigWAS was unclear.